# PhpStorm auto-completing HTML attributes with {braces} instead of "quotation marks"

Tags: html, autocomplete, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

**Problem**

I've recently upgraded to the latest PhpStorm (or what *was* the latest recently.)

```
PhpStorm 2017.2.4
Build #PS-172.4155.41, built on September 15, 2017
```

Since doing this, any time I type a HTML tag with an attribute, such as

```
<td class=
```

it auto-completes it JSX style, with curly braces, like so:

```
<td class={}
```

**Desired functionality**

It used to auto-complete it with quotation marks, like so:

```
<td class=""
```

And I'd like it to do this again.

**Caveat**

I'm able to disable the curly brace completion by disabling quotation mark completion setting, but of course, I don't get the quotation marks either.

[image]

**Question**

Is there a setting such that I can keep getting the "quotation mark" auto-complete, without getting the {curly brace} completion?

Comment: What's the JavaScript Language Level do you have selected for this project?

Comment: @LazyOne - Say no more. That was it, thanks! It had apparently defaulted to React JSX after the upgrade, possibly because it detected some React components in the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens if you have `React JSX` as default language level in the JavaScript settings (`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`).

The problem is fixed ([WEB-28894](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28894)) in [2017.3 EAP builds](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).

For 2017.2.x builds -- you will have to use different JavaScript Language Level.

---

Separate option was introduced in **2017.3.1** to control this behaviour: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/12/webstorm-2017-3-1/

Comment: Perfect. This resolved my issue. To elaborate, this can be changed in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`. Mine had been set to React JSX either automatically or by mistake. Setting it to `ECMAScript 6` and re-enabling the auto complete resolves the issue.