# Auto curly braces in WebStorm, check for modification

Tags: webstorm, curly-braces

I am using WebStorm to make React application.

Firstly, when I use JSX tag attribute, it automatically creates curly brace. How can I disable this option?

Secondly, when our source code was modified, many IDE shows us that this file is changed. In VSCode it's done like this:

[image]

but WebStorm is not. So I can't know whether this file has changed or not. How can I set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, when I use JSX tag attribute, it automatically creates curly brace. How can I disable this option?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949738/783119 -- should explain the situation (so I do not repeat the same here)

> Secondly, when our source code was modified, many IDE shows us that this file is changed.

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | General | Editor Tabs`
3. Enable `Mark modified tabs with asterisk` option.

[image]

Comment: First question has solved, but occurred another problem. when I write in single quote area, It create double quote automatically. like so <EmailInput _type='t"est"' /> ...

Comment: @JoonT Not sure what you mean (not a JS/React person myself) .. but check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779498/783119

Comment: it's not work.. when I type attribute, it create pair single quote. it's ok until here. but when I type something in pair single quote, it create double quote automatically.. like what I said above..

Comment: and I have another problem. when I change the language ReactJs to ECMAScript6 in Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript. It's work. but if application reboots or changes another options, it create curly brace automatically again..