# WebStorm, React & JSX curly braces autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, webstorm, jsx

I have an issue with WebStorm and React.

Within the render function I type my HTML (JSX) and when I type an attribute for an element, WebStorm will autocomplete it with curly braces instead of speech marks.

Anyone any ideas?

[image: Example problem]

Comment: Webstorm isn't going to know if you need a dynamic prop or not, so it assumes you will.

Comment: Thats for the reply. Webstorms example in their docs show that this should work thought:
https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/webstorm/files/2015/10/react_classname.gif

Comment: IDE version? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949738/783119 -- try 2017.3 EAP builds perhaps.

Comment: 2017.2.5. Nice find, I'll give this a go! Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can control this behavior:

```
File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Add for JSX attributes
```

The "Add for JSX attributes" setting is under the "Other" tab:

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what to add?

Comment: If you want "speech marks", then set it to "Quotes", or if you want it to try and be smart and show quotes if the attribute is such a type, you can set it to "Based on type". By default, it's set to "Braces".

Comment: Thanks Attila! I had a tough time finding the "Add for JSX attributes" option which was way under the "Other" tab in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Yes, Attila's answer is correct. It's a bit confusing though. This screenshot will complement Attila's answer.