# PhpStorm React JS code completion overrides PHP HTML

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Maybe this question has answers, but I find it hard to properly google it.

I have product with Laravel and React. And also I have PhpStorm, in which I work.

I set in Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> JavaScript

```
JavaScript language version React JSX
```

And it Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> PHP

```
PHP Language level: 7.1
```

And React settings override HTML code completion even in PHP (blade) files.

F.e. I want to type `class=""`, but it autocompletes `class=` with `{}`

```
class={}
```

How can I disable JS settings for React entirely for PHP files and why they work there at all (it's JS settings after all not PHP)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949738/783119 / https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/12/webstorm-2017-3-1/ ?

Comment: Kudos) Update to latest version solved the issue